# Контроллер как сервис в Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony3, dependency-injection, configuration

Доброго времени суток всем, возникла проблема с определением и настройкой контроллера как сервиса, суть проблемы - пишу бандл для подключения в другие проекты, есть в нем ApiController, объявлен как сервис, вот конфиг:

```
    test_apifile.controller.api:
    class: '%test_apifile.controller.api.class%'
    arguments:
      - '@event_dispatcher'
      - '@test_apifile.parameters.generator'
    public: true
```

Теперь из проекта, в который подключен этот бандл пытаюсь достучаться до контроллера следующим образом:

```
app_api_list:
   path: /api/v1/list_test
   defaults: { _controller: test_apifile.controller.api::indexAction }
```

И вот на данном этапе возникает проблема - ControllerResolver тупо не находит класс по id сервиса, а прописывать роут через референс нельзя, потому как в таком случае не будут инжектиться сервисы, необходимые для работы контроллера. Может кто сталкивался и подскажет как разрулить подобную ситуацию?

Answer (score 2):

Сервис:

```
default_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    public: true
```

Роутинг

```
default:
    path: /
    methods: [GET]
    controller: AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction
```

Comment: Хорошая попытка, но не катит, потому как при таком вызове контроллер оказывается не в внутри сервис контейнера, следовательно сервисы из него не инжектятся в конструктор. В принципе проблему уже решил - заключалась она в некорректном вызове indexAction через :: вместо :

Comment: Если вам не сложно, поясните фразу ` сервисы из него не инжектятся в конструктор`, не понял

Answer (score 1):

```
app_api_list:
   path: /api/v1/list_test
   defaults: { _controller: test_apifile.controller.api::indexAction }
```

в `test_apifile.controller.api::indexAction` меняем на `test_apifile.controller.api:indexAction` и проблема решена